# Is "be it by" here a set phrase?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is "be it by" here a set phrase? Or it's a clause, but where is the subject?

---

> The authors of the document, drawn up by the European commission’s
>   security union taskforce, write that the Schengen Border Code “did not
>   allow for the systematic consultation” of national and international
>   databases, leaving the security services unable to carry out basic
>   checks that could have avoided the ensuing bloodshed.
>
> “Another shared aspect of many of the recent attacks is movement
>   within the EU, **be it by** the perpetrators or their supporters in
>   preparation for an attack or subsequent escape; or to traffic the
>   means that support terrorists, such as illegal firearms and
>   explosives”, they write. “This raises the question of whether more can
>   be done to enhance security within the Schengen area. This could
>   include action to enhance police checks in internal border regions and
>   along main transport routes."

source: [EU taskforce highlights security failings that facilitated terror attacks](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/mar/14/eu-taskforce-highlights-security-failings-that-facilitated-terror-attacks)

Comment: "[Be it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214687/what-does-be-it-mean-in-this-passage)" is the phrase here. Similar to "whether it be."

Comment: "Be it " is a phrase in the subjunctive, "it"is the subject .

Answer (score 1):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

The subjunctive in English is used to form sentences that do not describe known objective facts. These include statements about one's state of mind, such as opinion, belief, purpose, intention, or desire. It contrasts with the indicative mood, which is used for statements of fact, such as He speaks English.

In Modern English, the subjunctive form of a verb often looks identical to the indicative form, and thus subjunctives are not a very visible grammatical feature of English. For most verbs, the only distinct subjunctive form is found in the third person singular of the present tense, where the subjunctive lacks the -s ending: It is necessary that he see a doctor (contrasted with the indicative he sees). However, the verb be has not only a distinct present subjunctive (be, as in I suggest that he be removed) but also a past subjunctive were (as in If he were rich, …).
Use of the present subjunctive  Edit

The main use of the English present subjunctive, called the mandative or jussive subjunctive,[2] occurs in that clauses (declarative content clauses; the word that is sometimes omitted in informal and conversational usage) expressing a circumstance that is desired, demanded, recommended, necessary, vel sim.. Such a clause may be dependent on verbs like insist, suggest, demand, prefer,[3] adjectives like necessary, desirable,[4] or nouns like recommendation, necessity;[5] it may be part of the expression in order that… (or some formal uses of so that…); it may also stand independently as the subject of a clause or as a predicative expression.

The form is called the present subjunctive because it resembles the present indicative in form, not because it need refer to the present time.[citation needed] In fact this form can equally well be used in sentences referring to past, future or hypothetical time (the time frame is normally expressed in the verb of the main clause).

Examples:

I insist (that) he leave now.
We asked that it be done yesterday.
It might be desirable that you not publish the story.

The subjunctive of the verb to be is used in this case because because the author is hypothesising and generalising as opposed to recounting or stating specific facts.